# How to create nested layout routing components in react router?

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to nest routes in a manner that would pre-set the layout for all the child routes of specified routes.

for instance:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Router path="/" component={Init}>
            <Router component={LayoutThreeCol}>
                <IndexRoute component={PageContainer}/>
            </Router>
            <Router component={LayoutTwoCol}>
                <Route path="/example" component={Example}/>
                <Route path="/another" component={Another}/>
            </Router>
        </Router>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

In this instance, `LayoutThreeCol` and `ListTwoCol` are the two layout components that encapsulate the child container and presentational components.
I need to be able to render as well as pass the props down to the child elements but I have been getting errors. However, think is the problem is caused by having the following line nested in two components child and parent respectively.

```
`{React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}`

So here is the code I am using an init file to instantiate the `mapStateToProps`

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from './ActionCreators'
import App from './App';

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
    return{
        Items: state.feedItems,
        universalNav: state.universalNav,
        height: state.height,
        width: state.width,
        isMobile: state.isMobile,
        isTablet: state.isTablet
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}


const Init = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

export default Init;
```

Here is the app file that I use as the wrapper

```
export default class App extends Component {

 render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <NavContainer />
                    {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a layout file.

```
export default class LayoutThreeCol extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="layout-3-col">
                <div className="layout-3-col-left">
                    //stuff goes here
                </div>
                <div className="layout-3-col-center">
                    {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})}
                </div>
                <div className="layout-3-col-right">
                    //stuff goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

layout two col
    export default class LayoutTwoCol extends Component{
        render(){
            return(
                
                    //omitted for brevity
                
            )
        }
    }

And the page container is a trivial presentational component.
How do I render multiple nested components as detailed in the above example?
Thanks

Comment: Your router config is very confusing since you only have one path `"/"`. What are you expecting to trigger loading more components in these nested routers.. also you just need one wrapping `Router` the child components should be `Route`

Comment: Have I answered your question? If so, can you accept my answer? If not, can you tell me what is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow !

In the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md), I only see one root `<Router>` component. Also, you don't have any path for LayoutTwo and LayoutThreeCol component in the router.

To render multiple nested components, you need to have nested `<Route>` components. This way, `this.props.children` will be a children component in the render method of the parent component.

If you want to pass props to the child routes, just add a parameter in the route :

`<Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />` 
In the `<Message>` element, you will have : {this.props.params.id}

I think that your router should look like this :

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={Init}>
            <Route path="layoutThree" component={LayoutThreeCol}>
                <IndexRoute component={PageContainer}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="layoutTwo" component={LayoutTwoCol}>
                <Route path="example" component={Example}/>
                <Route path="another" component={Another}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

**/layoutThree** : 
    In LayoutThreeMethod render method, `this.props.children` will be a `<PageContainer>` element by default!

**/layoutTwo/exemple** : In layoutTwoCol, `this.props.children` will be a `<Exemple/>` element!

Comment: this.props.children ends up being null?

Comment: @ShannenSmith I made a mistack path="/example" should be path="exemple" and path="/another" should be path="another" (see edit)

Comment: Alex thank you for the help but when I use your technique the LayoutThreeCol component doesn't render i.e. again the {this.props.children} in the App.js file is not functional. But I don't get any errors???

Comment: @ShannenSmith the LayoutThreeCol will only render on the /layoutThree route. What are you trying to do? This is not clear

Comment: When do you want LayoutThreeCol to be displaied